# Resizable JFreeChart inside a JPanel

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jfreechart

I know this question has been asked earlier ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13229097/javajfreechart-how-to-set-a-jfreecharts-chartpanel-resize-with-its-containe) ,[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21504141/how-to-add-a-jfreechart-to-a-jpanel-in-a-jframe) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8204544/how-to-resize-this-chart-in-jfreechart-netbeans)), but the offered solutions are not working. Hence, please don't mark it as duplicate. I am drawing a line chart using the JFreeChart. Then I put this chart inside a JPanel which is then put in a tabbedPane.
I know directly putting the JPanel in a JFrame makes it resizable but how can I do it this way?

```
public class DynamicLineAndTimeSeriesChart extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
    private ArrayList<TimeSeries> Series = new ArrayList<TimeSeries>();
    private ArrayList<Double> Last = new ArrayList<Double>();
    private String Id1;
    private Timer timer = new Timer(250, this);
    public DynamicLineAndTimeSeriesChart(String id) {

        Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
        int NoOfProc = runtime.availableProcessors();
        for (int i = 0; i < NoOfProc; i++) {
            Last.add(new Double(100.0));
            Series.add(new TimeSeries("Core" + i, Millisecond.class));
        }
        Id1 = id;
        final TimeSeriesCollection dataset = new TimeSeriesCollection();
        for (int i = 0; i < NoOfProc; i++) {
            dataset.addSeries(this.Series.get(i));
        }
        final JFreeChart chart = createChart(dataset);
        timer.setInitialDelay(1000);
        chart.setBackgroundPaint(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);

        //Created JPanel to show graph on screen
        final JPanel content = new JPanel(new GridLayout());
        final ChartPanel chartPanel = new ChartPanel(chart);
        content.add(chartPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        content.revalidate();
        this.add(content);

        timer.start();
    }
```

createChart is a method of type JFreeChart. 
This class is called in another class

```
JPanel main = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
main.add(demo);
jTabbedPane1.add("Core", main);
demo.setVisible(true);
```

The frame designing was done using NetBeans.
I have tried all the solution like changing the layouts from BorderLayout to GridBagLayout and even the one mentioned [here](http://www.jfree.org/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?p=75516).

Comment: maybe content.pack() ?

Comment: *"I know this question has been asked earlier, but the offered solutions are not working."*  Where?  Links please..

Comment: What is the problem exactly ? Do you want  chartPanel to autoresize when you resize content?

Comment: [Don't use `setPreferredSize()` when you really mean to override `getPreferredSize()`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7229226/230513).

Comment: @AndrewThompson Have done the edits.

Comment: @JannisAlexakis I want the chartPanel to resize as the container (JPanel here) is resized.

Answer (score 1):

`BorderLayout.CENTER` should let the `ChartPanel` grow as the frame is resized. I'm guessing that you have a `JPanel` with a `FlowLayout`, which keeps on using the chart panel's preferred size. Since `FlowLayout` is the default, you may have to look for it.

Edit: There's a complete example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15715096/261156) that adds a line chart to a tabbed pane.

Edit: Your `DynamicLineAndTimeSeriesChart` has the default `FlowLayout`; I think you want a `GridLayout`.

```
public DynamicLineAndTimeSeriesChart(String id) {
    this.setLayout(new GridLayout());
    …
}
```

Comment: Can you please specify? I have used two JPanels and both their layouts have been changed to borderlayout.

Comment: I don't know why that wouldn't work; can you edit your question to show a complete example?

Comment: Have done the edits, but posting the complete code was not possible so I posted the relevant part. Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing all of your code it can only be speculation. But, as a workaround, you could make your JPanel listen for resize events with a ComponentListener, something like this :

```
 content.addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter(){
        public void componentResized(ActionEvent e){
            chartPanel.setSize(content.getSize());
        }
    });
```

Comment: Still no change, the graph is not resizing.

Comment: Have you tried monitoring the veriables ? What´s the size of the chartpanel and it´s container right after chartPanel.setSize(content.getSize()); I can´t think of a reason why that shouldn´t work.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I managed to solve it like this:
(1) create a custom class which extends JPanel
(2) get the size somehow, that you would like to pass to your chart
(3) create a method which returns a "ChartPanel" object like this:

```
ChartPanel chart() {
    //... custom code here
    JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createPieChart(title, pieDataset, false, false, false );`enter code here`
    // Now: this is the trick to manage setting the size of a chart into a panel!:
    return new ChartPanel(chart) { 
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(width, height);
        }
    };
}
```

I prepared a SSCCE to let you know how it works:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartFactory;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartPanel;
import org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart;
import org.jfree.data.general.DefaultPieDataset;

public class MyPieChart extends JPanel {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        example1();
        example2();
        example3();
    }

    public static void example1() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBounds(50, 80, 100, 100);
        MyPieChart piePanel = new MyPieChart("Example 1", dataset(), panel);
        panel.add(piePanel);
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setLayout(null); 
        frame.setBounds(10, 10, 200, 300);
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void example2() {
        MyPieChart piePanel = new MyPieChart("Example 2", dataset(), 30, 50, 100, 100);
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setLayout(null); 
        frame.setBounds(210, 10, 200, 300);
        frame.add(piePanel);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void example3() {
        MyPieChart piePanel = new MyPieChart("Example 3", dataset(), 100, 100);
        piePanel.setLocation(0,0);
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setLayout(null); 
        frame.setBounds(410, 10, 200, 300);
        frame.add(piePanel);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    static ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> dataset() {
        ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> dataset = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
        dataset.add(row( "Tom", "LoggedIn", "Spain" ));
        dataset.add(row( "Jerry", "LoggedOut", "England" ));
        dataset.add(row( "Gooffy", "LoggedOut", "France" ));
        return dataset;
    }

    static ArrayList<String> row(String name, String actualState, String country) {
        ArrayList<String> row = new ArrayList<String>();
        row.add(name); row.add(actualState); row.add(country); 
        return row;
    }

    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> dataset;
    DefaultPieDataset pieDataset = new DefaultPieDataset(); 
    int width, height, posX, posY;
    int colState = 1;
    String title;
    String LoggedIn = "LoggedIn";
    String LoggedOut = "LoggedOut";

    public MyPieChart(String title, ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> dataset, int...args) {

        if(args.length==2) {
            this.width = args[0];
            this.height = args[1];
            this.setSize(width, height);
        }
        else if(args.length==4) {
            this.posX = args[0];
            this.posY = args[1];
            this.width = args[2];
            this.height = args[3];
            this.setBounds(posX, posY, width, height);
        }
        else {
            System.err.println("Error: wrong number of size/position arguments");
            return;
        }

        this.title = title;
        this.dataset = dataset;
        this.add(chart());
    }

    public MyPieChart(String title, ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> dataset, JPanel panel) {
        this.title = title;
        this.dataset = dataset;
        this.width = panel.getWidth();
        this.height = panel.getHeight();
        this.setBounds(panel.getBounds());
        this.add(chart());
    }

    ChartPanel chart() {

        int totalLoggedIn = 0;
        int totalLoggedOut = 0;

        for(ArrayList<String> user : dataset) {
            if(user.get(colState).equals(LoggedIn)) totalLoggedIn++;
            else totalLoggedOut++;
        }
        pieDataset.clear();
        pieDataset.setValue(LoggedIn +": "+ totalLoggedIn, totalLoggedIn);
        pieDataset.setValue(LoggedOut +": "+ totalLoggedOut, totalLoggedOut);

        JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createPieChart(title, pieDataset, false, false, false );

        return new ChartPanel(chart) { // this is the trick to manage setting the size of a chart into a panel!
            public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                return new Dimension(width, height);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

I really hope it helps!